# Odd error in Outlook 2016 Pro Plus notifications

Tags: outlook

We are piloting a new desktop based upon Windows 10 and Office 2016 Pro Plus (not 365).   We have AD configured to show employee photos.

For the first day or so after the new image is deployed for a user, the "toast" notifications from Outlook for email include the employee photo, if one is available.  Afterwards, the photo in the toast notification is replaced by the Outlook icon.  This is consistent and reproducible across a wide variety of PCs and users.

Any ideas on what could be happening?

Comment: Can you share a image to clarify what you mean by "toast notification"? If you meant the pop up notification in Windows notification center at the right lower corner, I didn't see the photo of the sender either when testing in my Outlook 2016 on Windows 10.
By the way, have you checked if the photo can be seen properly in the message header?

Comment: Yes, I mean the pop up message in the lower right corner.   The actual email windows show the photo.